# Backend GET Request has failed, Axios/React

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, react-fullstack

I'm building my first heavy front end app, and i'm building a search function with my own app.

Currently, I just want to fetch data with the api endpoint, which works through postman/my own browser etc when running, however my get axios request is erroring.

See below:

I have the two following variable. For example, it's a user query, driven by the input for 'query'. As shown, the desired endpoint is: http://localhost:5000/api/role/title?title=Programmer.

If I make a direct request through post and browser, I am also using a custom hook Debouncer I made, which I assume is quite self-explanatory.

```
    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);


  const prepareSearchQuery = (query) => {
        const url = `http://localhost:5000/api/role/title?title=${query}`;

        //replaces bad query in the url
        return encodeURI(url);
    }

    const searchRolePosition = async () => {
        if(!searchQuery || searchQuery.trim() === "")
            return;

        setLoading(true);

        const URL = prepareSearchQuery(searchQuery);

        const response = await axios.get(URL).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });

        if(response) {
            console.log("Response", response.data);


   useDebounce(searchQuery, 500, searchRolePosition)
```

As I boot up the app, it does not error, but once I type the string 'Programmer', to reach that endpoint, I get the following console.log.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/role/title?title=Programmer' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/role/title?title=Programmer' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

```
VM2546:1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/role/title?title=Programmer net::ERR_FAILED 200
```

My component is currently:

```
 <SearchInput placeholder = "Search for Roles" 
                                onFocus={expandedContainer} 
                                ref={inputRef}
                                value={searchQuery}
                                onChange={changeHandler}
                                />
```

It still logs my value as Programmer, indicating it is indeed working, however it is unable to fetch any data as it fails.

For those interested, the API looks like this. As said, it does work on Postman and Browser:

```
router.get("/title", async (req,res) => {
  const qNew = req.query.new;
  const qTitle = req.query.title;

  try{
    let roles; 
    if(qNew){
      roles = await Role.find().sort({createdAt: -1}).limit(1)
    } else if (qTitle){
      roles = await Role.find({title: {
        $in: [qTitle],
      },
    });
    }else {
      roles = await Role.find();
    }
    res.status(200).json(roles)
  }catch(err){
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }

} )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the HTTP header:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000`

Comment: Hi Mohammadreza, which header?

Comment: are you using postman? if yes goto Headers/ temporary headers / host : http://localhost:3000

Comment: if you using Django goto setting and add this line: ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

Comment: The exact directive for setting headers depends on your web server. In Apache, add a line such as the following to the server's configuration (within the appropriate <Directory>, <Location>, <Files>, or <VirtualHost> section). The configuration is typically found in a .conf file (httpd.conf and apache.conf are common names for these), or in an .htaccess file.

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'origin-list'